# Issue seeing files in dired directory or shell on remote machine

Tags: dired, tramp, shell

This used to work fine but seems to have broken today and I have not knowingly made any explicit changes to configuration.

If I use a standard terminal (mac) and ssh into my server I can visit a path that is external storage and see the files. In this case `/projects`.

But if I use Emacs and I either run `M-x shell` on the server and try and visit the same dir or open that dir in Dired I get a blank. i.e I can not see or access any files or folders in this external storage area.

I have tried pressing `g` to refresh. I have tried running `tramp-cleanup-this-connection`. I have restarted Emacs and my mac.

How do I reset Emacs for this to work again?

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, post a step-by-step recipe from `emacs -Q` to repro the problem (and maybe file an Emacs bug report).

Comment: Furthermore, which Emacs/Tramp version are you using? There was a Tramp error using secondary groups, which has been fixed in the Emacs repository. If you use emacs build from there, please pull and recompile, and try, again.

Comment: This has now started working again. I am not sure if it was me trying a different version of emacs and it working ( 26.1) , but then going back to the version I normally use (also 26.1 but the ess 'ready' version) or if something on the server changed.  
Thanks for your help.